# Como hacer que java me reconozca un parrafo

Tags: java, string

solamente con una consulta. 
Se trata que estoy creando un juego en java parecido a Tamagochi de los 90's. 
Tiene que tener la opcion de crear Pokemon, en donde se ingrese el nombre del pokemon; ademas de ello el jugador puede ingresar una "imagen" de caracteres para su pokemon que esta creando.

mi codigo es el siguiente.

```
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de su Pokemon");
        nombreDelPokemon[contador]=scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la imagen de su Pokemon");
        imagenDelPokemon=scanner.next();
```

Pero al momento de leer la variable imagenDelPokemon solo me imprime la primera linea de la imagen del pokemon.

la imagen del pokemon es la siguiente:

```
       ,     ,_
       |`\    `;;,            ,;;'
       |  `\    \ '.        .'.'
       |    `\   \  '-""""-' /
       `.     `\ /          |`
         `>    /;   _     _ \ 
          /   / |       .    ;
         <  (`";\ ()   ~~~  (/_
          ';;\  `,     __ _.-'` )
            >;\          `   _.'
            `;;\          \-'
              ;/           \ _
              |   ,"".     .` \
              |      _|   '   /
               ;    /")     .;-,
          jgs   \    /  __   .-'
                 \,_/-"`  `-'
```

Quisiera saber como hacer para que Java me lea todo el parrafo. 
Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar únicamente `scanner.next()` estás pidiendo que te guarde la siguiente "palabra" ingresada, es decir te guardará todo el texto que haya antes de un espacio, si por el contrario usas `scanner.nextLine()` le pedirías que guarde el texto completo que sea ingresado en la siguiente linea.

Usar `next()` puede causar que tu software no funcione bien al momento de usarlo, por ejemplo que tengas:

```
   System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de su Pokemon");
   nombreDelPokemon[contador]=scanner.next();
   System.out.println("Ingrese la imagen de su Pokemon");
   imagenDelPokemon=scanner.next();<i>
```

Y el usuario ingrese en la primera pregunta 
"Mi pokemon"

Automáticamente la variable `nombreDelPokemon[contador]` sería igual a "Mi" y la variable `imagenDelPokemon` sería igual a "Pokemon".

en la documentación de java puedes leer un poco más acerca de esto https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo mejor para esta forma de trabajar es usar la función `netxtLine()`, bien leyendo un número determinado de líneas (yo aconsejaría esto) o bien obligando a que la última línea posea un código específico.

Para el primer caso, yo haría algo así:

```
int lineasImagen=12;
System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de su Pokemon");
string nombreDelPokemon=scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingrese la imagen de su Pokemon");
List<String> imagenPokemon=new AraryList<String>();

for (int i=0;i<lineasImagen;i++){
    imagenPokemon.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Por supuesto, deberías controlar que la lectura de cada línea fuera correcta y demás. Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Ya lo he implementado y me funciona bien.

Comment: Me alegra leerlo!